# Spring boot - Service class is null

Tags: java, spring

I'm dwelling with an autoWired service class which is null in a Spring Boot application.. Every object is instantiated by Spring, so I don't know why it happens.

The situation is:
I have a Rele.java class which is the following:

```
@Component
public class Rele {

    private Pin pin;
    private GpioController gpio;
    private GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Rele.class);
    private Interruttore interruttore;
    @Autowired AccensioneService accensioneService;

    public Rele(){

    }

    // Costruttore

    public Rele(Pin pin, Interruttore interruttore) {
        this.pin = pin;
        this.gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        this.relePin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(pin, "MyRele", PinState.LOW);
        this.interruttore = interruttore;
    }

    public void lightOn() {
        try {

        if (relePin.isLow()) {
            relePin.high();
            updateAccensione(interruttore, true);
            logger.debug("Rele acceso");
        }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.debug("relepin è:" +relePin);
            logger.debug("gpio è:"+gpio);
        }
    }

    public void lightOff() {
        if (relePin.isHigh()) {
            relePin.low();
            updateAccensione(interruttore, false);
            logger.debug("Rele spento");
        }
    }

    public void updateAccensione(Interruttore interruttore, boolean acceso) {

        Date lastDateAccensione = new Date();

        try {
            logger.debug("accensioneService is"+accensioneService);
        lastDateAccensione = accensioneService.findLastDate(interruttore);
        } catch(NullPointerException npe){
            logger.debug("accensioneService is: "+accensioneService);
            logger.error("Error is:", npe);
            lastDateAccensione = new Timestamp(lastDateAccensione.getTime());

        }
        Accensione accensione = new Accensione();
        Date date = new Date();
        logger.debug("lastDate:" + lastDateAccensione);
        accensione.setDateTime(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        accensione.setInterruttore(interruttore);
        accensione.setIsLit(acceso);
        accensione.setLastDateTime(lastDateAccensione);
        logger.debug("Accensione è:"+accensione.toString());
        accensioneService.saveAccensione(accensione);

    }

    public Pin getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(Pin pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public Interruttore getInterruttore() {
        return interruttore;
    }

    public void setInterruttore(Interruttore interruttore) {
        this.interruttore = interruttore;
    }

    public GpioPinDigitalOutput getRelePin() {
        return relePin;
    }

    public void setRelePin(GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin) {
        this.relePin = relePin;
    }

    public GpioController getGpio() {
        return gpio;
    }

    public void setGpio(GpioController gpio) {
        this.gpio = gpio;
    }
}
```

When trying to call for `updateAccensione`, this is null.
Rele is created from a Controller, by this method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/illuminazione")
    public ResponseEntity<Illuminazione> findIlluminazione(@RequestParam(value="idLuce") int idLuce,
                                                        @RequestParam(value="lit") boolean lit,
                                                        @RequestParam(value="suServer") boolean suServer) {

        Illuminazione illuminazione = new Illuminazione();
        Date lastDate = illuminazioneService.findLastDate(idLuce);
        illuminazione.setLastDateTime(lastDate);
        illuminazione.setIdLuce(idLuce);
        illuminazione.setIsLit(lit);
        Date date = new Date();
        illuminazione.setDateTime(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        illuminazioneService.saveIlluminazione(illuminazione);
        logger.debug("Aggiornata luce " + idLuce + " accesa: "+lit);
        //managing rele
        if(suServer){
        //check if status has changed

        Luce luce = luceService.findById(idLuce);
        int idInterruttore = luce.getInterruttore().getIdInterruttore();
        Interruttore interruttore = interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);
        Rele rele = releService.findByInterruttore(interruttore);
        logger.debug("rele="+rele.toString());

        if(lit){
        rele.lightOn();
        } else {
        rele.lightOff();
        }

        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Illuminazione>(illuminazione,HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Rele is created, i find it in my logs.
AccensioneService is an interface, it's concrete implementation is AccensioneServiceImpl:

```
@Service("accensioneService")
@Transactional
public class AccensioneServiceImpl implements AccensioneService{

    @Autowired AccensioneDao dao;

    @Override
    public void saveAccensione(Accensione accensione) {
        dao.saveAccensione(accensione);

    }

    @Override
    public Accensione findById(int id) {

        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Date findLastDate(Interruttore interruttore) {

        return dao.findLastDate(interruttore);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean findLastStatus(int id) {

        return dao.findLastStatus(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAccensione(Interruttore interruttore) {


    }
}
```

I don't know if anything else is needed. AccensioneService is also called in other methods and controller, and it works... only when called inside Rele gives me this error...

Comment: Your `releService` seems to be returning an unmanaged bean. The fact that you have multiple constructors for `Rele` strongly suggests that you are in fact creating unmanaged instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to add**

You must be calling `new Rele()` or the other `Rele(Pin, Interruttore )` constructor?  If you are calling these in your code, the accensioneService will be null because **Spring** needs to create the bean, you **cannot create it with its constructor if you want beans Autowired into it or for it to be Autowired.**  If you want it to behave like this, Spring has to know about it, so it has to be in (and come from) the Spring context.

Put a log statement in each constructor and find out who is calling them, and fix that so that instead of calling the constructor, you get the bean from Spring.

**Old answer below**

You need to post this method to be sure:

`Rele rele = releService.findByInterruttore(interruttore);`

I'll bet you are creating `rele` somewhere by calling `new Rele()`, which is not correct.  You need to let Spring create it for you.

You did not post enough code to give further suggestions.

Also, you say `this is null`. What **this** are you talking about?

Comment: `accensioneService`is null. When i call `Rele rele = releService.findByInterruttore(interruttore);` the logger soon after returns me something like this: `rele=it.besmart.parkserver.Rele@b10936`...

Comment: I saw I was creating the new rele from inside another class, you were right, now I have another problem because i don't know how to create the Rele from Spring Boot giving them an `interruttore`and a `pin`. Simply annotate the Rele.java as @Bean? Does it works with Spring boot?

Comment: That's a separate question, but yes, you should be able to do that.  You could also create a factory that is Spring aware and that will create your `Rele` class for you and do the injection.  There are many ways.  Post a new SO question if you have one.